# change size button in runtime (wpf)

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

Why size does not change in IsMouseOver?

```
                   <Style x:Key="GlassButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid>
                    <!-- Background Layer -->
                    <Ellipse Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                    <!-- Refraction Layer -->
                    <Ellipse x:Name="RefractionLayer">
                        <Ellipse.Fill>
                            <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0.496,1.052">
                                <RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <ScaleTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" ScaleX="1.5" ScaleY="1.5"/>
                                        <TranslateTransform X="0.02" Y="0.3"/>
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                            </RadialGradientBrush>
                        </Ellipse.Fill>
                    </Ellipse>
                    <!-- Reflection Layer -->
                    <Path x:Name="ReflectionLayer" VerticalAlignment="Top" Stretch="Fill">
                        <Path.RenderTransform>
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleY="0.5" />
                        </Path.RenderTransform>
                        <Path.Data>
                            <PathGeometry>
                                <PathFigure IsClosed="True" StartPoint="98.999,45.499">
                                    <BezierSegment Point1="98.999,54.170" Point2="89.046,52.258" Point3="85.502,51.029"/>
                                    <BezierSegment
                            IsSmoothJoin="True"
                            Point1="75.860,47.685"
                            Point2="69.111,45.196"
                            Point3="50.167,45.196"/>
                                    <BezierSegment Point1="30.805,45.196" Point2="20.173,47.741" Point3="10.665,51.363"/>
                                    <BezierSegment
                            IsSmoothJoin="True"
                            Point1="7.469,52.580"
                            Point2="1.000,53.252"
                            Point3="1.000,44.999"/>
                                    <BezierSegment Point1="1.000,39.510" Point2="0.884,39.227" Point3="2.519,34.286"/>
                                    <BezierSegment
                            IsSmoothJoin="True"
                            Point1="9.106,14.370"
                            Point2="27.875,0"
                            Point3="50,0"/>
                                    <BezierSegment Point1="72.198,0" Point2="91.018,14.466" Point3="97.546,34.485"/>
                                    <BezierSegment
                            IsSmoothJoin="True"
                            Point1="99.139,39.369"
                            Point2="98.999,40.084"
                            Point3="98.999,45.499"/>
                                </PathFigure>
                            </PathGeometry>
                        </Path.Data>
                        <Path.Fill>
                            <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0.498,0.526">
                                <RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <ScaleTransform
                               CenterX="0.5"
                               CenterY="0.5"
                               ScaleX="1"
                               ScaleY="1.997"/>
                                        <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0.5"/>
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                            </RadialGradientBrush>
                        </Path.Fill>
                    </Path>
                    <!-- ContentPresenter -->
                    <ContentPresenter Margin="0,2,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>


                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"/>
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="200"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="RefractionLayer" Property="Fill">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0.496,1.052">
                                    <RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                        <TransformGroup>
                                            <ScaleTransform
                                  CenterX="0.5"
                                  CenterY="0.5"
                                  ScaleX="1.5"
                                  ScaleY="1.5"/>
                                            <TranslateTransform  X="0.02" Y="0.3"/>
                                        </TransformGroup>
                                    </RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                    <GradientStop  Offset="1" Color="#00000000"/>
                                    <GradientStop Offset="0.45" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
                                </RadialGradientBrush>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Setter TargetName="ReflectionLayer" Property="Fill">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0.498,0.526">
                                    <RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                        <TransformGroup>
                                            <ScaleTransform
                                  CenterX="0.5"
                                  CenterY="0.5"
                                  ScaleX="1"
                                  ScaleY="1.997"/>
                                            <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0.5"/>
                                        </TransformGroup>
                                    </RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                    <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
                                    <GradientStop Offset="0.85" Color="#BBFFFFFF"/>
                                    <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#00000000"/>
                                </RadialGradientBrush>
                            </Setter.Value>


                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="RefractionLayer" Property="Fill">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0.496,1.052">
                                    <RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                        <TransformGroup>
                                            <ScaleTransform
                                  CenterX="0.5"
                                  CenterY="0.5"
                                  ScaleX="1.5"
                                  ScaleY="1.5"/>
                                            <TranslateTransform X="0.02" Y="0.3"/>
                                        </TransformGroup>
                                    </RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>

                                </RadialGradientBrush>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Setter TargetName="ReflectionLayer" Property="Fill">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0.498,0.526">
                                    <RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                        <TransformGroup>
                                            <ScaleTransform
                                  CenterX="0.5"
                                  CenterY="0.5"
                                  ScaleX="1"
                                  ScaleY="1.997"/>
                                            <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0.5"/>
                                        </TransformGroup>
                                    </RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                </RadialGradientBrush>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Example Usage :

```
 <Button Style="{DynamicResource GlassButton}"  Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="534,262,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
```

Comment: Could you try changing the properties to ActualHeight and RenderWidth for me and see what happens?

Also are you sure the template is binding to your button? Can you put up the code where you create the button?

Comment: I want to change the size button

Comment: Is that an example usage? Or is that exactly how that button is created in your code? Something else might interfere with the size that you're not showing us. Did you try changing the properties to ActualHeight and RenderWidth? What happened?

Comment: What is the correct code ?What way do you use?

Comment: That example is correct, but is that the way you've actually used it in your code?

Comment: How do you use which code? Your example or changing the properties? To change the properties replace where you've written <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"/> with <Setter Property="ActualWidth" Value="200"/> and tell me if that helps. Also try <Setter Property="RenderWidth" Value="200"/>

Comment: @mrJack let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2072/discussion-between-nick-udell-and-mrjack)

Answer (score 2):

You have a property setting precedence issue. See the precedence table on [WPFTutorial.net](http://www.wpftutorial.net/DependencyProperties.html) (see Value resolution strategy section).

Remove the `Height` and `Width` settings on your `Button` and if you need the initial sizes add these setters to your style:

```
<Setter Property="Height" Value="23"/>
<Setter Property="Width" Value="75"/>
```

And, be careful with Blend adding sizes for you....